# Regex NOT or exclude match

Tags: regex, regex-negation

How do I make regex match and exclude certain character. 
For example, I am making an regex for all country's TDL match.

```
[a-z]{1,}((?!.ru)|.kr|.lt|.cn|.uk|.id|)
```

or

```
[a-z]{1,}.([a-z]{1,})
```

gsdfg.ru <- This shall match

sgkjsr.us <- only .us should not match or should excluded

Comment: since you are listing all endings maybe just do not put it into matching group?

Comment: Listing out all of them (a few hundred, but do-able by using a loop) is one possible solution. It will allow you to match only country TLD without allowing other things you may not want to match.

Comment: Do you want to match just `.tld` or the whole `domain.tld`?

Comment: It's not clear from the text, on `sgkjsr.us` do you want the whole string to be rejected, or you want to capture just `sgkjsr`, excluding the `.us` suffix, while on `gsdfg.ru` the whole string should be captured as a match?

Comment: @SergiuDumitriu - I want the whole text rejected if it is .us TDL. and accept all text other than .us

Comment: For the sake of brevity and readability, `{1,}` (one or more of) can be shortened to `+`, if cc tlds have 2-chars in them you should use [a-z]{2} for them.  Also the dot can be factored out of all the sub patterns: `\.([a-z]{2})

Answer (score 3):

This should work (blacklisting):

```
\.(?!us|eu)[a-z]{2}$
```

It searches for a dot (`\.`), which isn't followed by `us` or `eu` (`(?!us|eu)`), and is followed by two lowercase letters (`[a-z]{2}`), right at the end of the string (`$`).

This should also work (whitelisting):

```
\.(?:ru|kr|cn|uk|id)$
```

It searches for a dot (`\.`), which is followed by one of `ru`, `kr` ... or `id`, right at the end of the string (`$`). I used `(?:...)` instead of a simple `(...)` so that the group doesn't create a capture. If you actually need to capture the country code for later user, feel free to remove the `?:` part.

Comment: `([a-z]{3,}\.(?!us|com)[a-z]{2})` seems to doing the job. Thanks! +1